# Geodesics of a rotating sphere

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

I know when we live on a rotating sphere we feel virtual forces. By these forces how can we define our geodesics? l think these geodesics are different with the geodesics of a non-rotating sphere.

Comment: You use a novel expression: 'virtual forces'. I'm guessing you are referring to consequences of inertia. If an object is located on a rotating sphere, then in order to co-rotate with the sphere a centripetal force is required. In the absence of required centripetal force the object will proceed to move in a straight line, so the object will depart from the sphere. I recommend you rewrite the question, stating it in terms of concequences of inertia.

Comment: I assume you are referring to a rotating celestial body, such as the Earth. A rotating celestial body has an equatorial bulge. For instance, in the case of the Earth the equatorial bulge is such that the distance from the Earth's geometric center to the equator is about 20 kilometer more than the distance from the Earth's geometric center to the poles. The Earth's equatorial bulge is in equilibrium with the rotation rate. As a consequence: fluid on the earth is co-rotating with the Earth. This effect can be described in terms of geodesics. So: do you allow for equatorial bulge?

Comment: I mean that for example Azimuth is a geodesic of a non rotating sphere, but for an observer who lives on a rotating sphere geodesics may be different. Because he feels coriolis force and centrifugal force... .Is it true?